# What does `touch` in Dockerfile do?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am re-using a `Dockerfile` with these contents:

```
ADD dist /dist/
ARG JAR_FILE
ADD target/${JAR_FILE} /target/app.jar
RUN sh -c 'touch /target/app.jar'
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "-c", "java -jar /target/app.jar"]
```

I understand all lines except the one with `touch`. [This site](https://djcodes.wordpress.com/dev-tools/docker-basics-and-setup-on-ubuntu/docker-spring-boot-with-docker/) says:

> `RUN sh -c ‘touch /app.jar’` – touch our file so it has modification time (Docker creates all container files in an “unmodified” state by default)

I understand that touching a file changes its modification date. Why does Docker need a timestamp on the file, or why is it a good practice to do so?

Comment: In your case, they just want to update the access date and/or modification date of your file app.jar , Nothing more than that !
By default, touch sets both the date of last file modification and the date of last file access to the current time.

Comment: Thanks @SyedSaadAhmed. I understand what the touch command does and I edited the question to reflect that. What I don't understand is: Why do we need to change the timestamp?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because of Docker layer caching, in a lot of common cases the `touch` command won't do *anything*.  If the jar file has changed then the ADD command will include it in the image with its last-modified time from the host ("it is copied individually [along with its metadata](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#add)"); since that's presumably recently, the `touch` command will update it to seconds later.  If the jar file hasn't changed then Docker will skip both the ADD and RUN commands and use the filesystem output from the previous time you ran it, with the previous run's timestamp.

If the jar file is just being used as an input to `java -jar` then its last-modified time shouldn't be relevant to anything either.

I'd guess you can safely remove the `touch` command with no ill effects.  There are a couple of unnecessary `sh -c` invocations that don't matter and just clutter things.  I'd guess this Dockerfile to be functionally equivalent:

```sh
# Prefer COPY to ADD, unless you explicitly want Docker to fetch
# URLs or unpack archives
COPY dist /dist/
ARG JAR_FILE
COPY target/${JAR_FILE} /target/app.jar
EXPOSE 8080
# Prefer CMD to ENTRYPOINT, if nothing else so `docker run imagename sh` works
# Split simple commands into words yourself
CMD ["java", "-jar", "/target/app.jar"]
```

Comment: The code seems functionally equivalent and the proposed code works, so I will accept the answer.